# Why does my Datastax node with solr enabled not index my ColumnFamily?

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

This is my status after reindex:

lastModified: 3 minutes ago, version: 5, numDocs: 0, maxDoc:0, 
deletedDocs:-, current: OK, indexing: no

My columnfamily has data but the index doesn't show any data. 
I don't know why?

Comment: How did you create the Solr core? Did you use dsetool or curl it manually? Did you upload a schema.xml and solr config? If you go to the Solr UI (http://hostname:8983/solr/) there's a section to view events in the logs. It'll have errors in red. That will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I used DSE tool and it added the solr config and schema.xml  automatically. The Solr UI does not show any errors in red just regular logging. Any ideas why the index doesn't show data?